# Data within a bootstrap modal form doesn't transfer to a MySQL table using php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on this for some time now by looking at previous answers to questions, but still doesn't work.

I'm trying to get a MySQL table updated with the data in a Bootstrap Modal form when submitting via PHP. The php code below works when using it in a previous website (which doesn't use bootstrap).

The issue I get is on submit; the form passes the javascript validation and then opens the register.php file. When I look at the MySQL table the data hasn't transferred and the webpage is just blank with no content (url comes up as `http://localhost/BootstrapEx/php/register.php`).

Please can someone help as to why the data within the form doesn't transfer to MySQL when using Twitter Bootstrap and a way to fix this?

I know I have to change/update the security, validation and error pages within the php file, but at this stage all I want it to do is load the data into the MySQL table. I temporary created Thankyou.html, SystemError.html and RegError.html as you will see in the php code just to see if those pages opened.

Please find the code below:

Html: Just the modal form section

```
<div class="modal fade" id ="Register" role ="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class = "modal-content">
              <div class = "modal-header">
                <h4>Registration Screen</h4>
              </div>
            <div class ="modal-body">




              <form name="myForm" role="form" action="php/register.php" method ="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">


              <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label><span>*</span>
                <input type="FirstName" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="fname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label><span>*</span>
                <input type="Surname" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter your last name or surname" name="lname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label><span>*</span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="psword1">Password</label><span>*</span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="psword1" placeholder="Password" name="psword1">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psword2">Confirm Password</label><span>*</span>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="psword2" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="psword2">
              </div>

              <div class = "form-group">
              <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
              <button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes">Register</button>
            </fieldset>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      </form>
```

register.php file (please excuse the error sections, these will be updated once the data submits into the table).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    require ('php/mysqli_connect.php'); 

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        $errors = array(); // Initialize an error array.
        // Check for a first name:
        if (empty($_POST['fname'])) 
        {
            $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your first name.';
        } else 
        {
            $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['fname']));
        }
            // Check for a last name:
        if (empty($_POST['lname'])) 
        {
            $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your last name.';
        } else 
        {
            $ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['lname']));
        }
            // Check for an email address:
        if (empty($_POST['email'])) 
        {
            $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
        } else 
        {
            $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['email']));
        }
            // Check for a password and match against the confirmed password:
        if (!empty($_POST['psword1'])) 
        {
            if ($_POST['psword1'] != $_POST['psword2']) 
            {
                $errors[] = 'Your two passwords did not match.';
            } else 
            {
                $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, trim($_POST['psword1']));
            }
        } else 
        {
            $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
        }

        if (empty($errors)) 
        { // If everything's OK.
            // Register the user in the database...

                // Make the query:

            $q = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, fname, lname, email, psword, registration_date) VALUES (' ', '$fn', '$ln', '$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW() )";    
            $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query.
            if ($result) 
            { // If it ran OK

                header("Location:http://localhost/BootstrapEx/Thankyou.html");

                echo '<p>Fields Loaded</p>'; 
                exit();

            } else 
            { // If it did not run OK
                // Error message:

               header("Location:http://localhost/BootstrapEx/SystemError.html");
                echo '<h2>System Error</h2>
                <p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; 
                //Debugging message:
                echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br>Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
            } // End of if ($result)
                mysqli_close($dbcon); // Close the database connection.

                exit();
        } else 
        { // Report the errors

             header("Location:http://localhost/BootstrapEx/RegError.html");
                echo '<h2>Error!</h2>
                <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br>';
                foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Echo each error
                echo " - $msg<br>\n";
                }
                echo '</p><h3>Please try again.</h3><p><br></p>';
        }// End of if (empty($errors))
    } // End of the main Submit conditional
}
?>
```

MySQL php connection file (username, passwords etc details changed)

```
<?php
//This file provides the information for accessing the database and connecting to
//mysql. It also sets the language coding to utf-8.


DEFINE ('DB_USER', '****')
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '****')
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '****')

$dbcon = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL:' .mysqli_connect_error());
language encoding
mysqli_set_charset($dbcon, 'utf8');

?>
```

Javascript Validation

```
function validateForm() {

    // First name validation
    var w = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["psword1"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myForm"]["psword2"].value;
    var atpos = y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = y.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (w == null || w == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    else if (/[^a-zA-z'-]/.test(w)) {
        alert("First Name not completed, please only use letters & spaces with either (') or (-).");
        return false;
    }

    // Last name validation

    else if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    else if (/[^a-zA-z'-]/.test(w)) {
        alert("Last name not completed, please only use letters & spaces with either (') or (-).");
        return false;
    }

    // Email validation

    else if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Email address must be completed");
        return false;
    }


    else if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    // Password Validation

    else if (z == null || z == "") {
        alert("Password must be entered");
        return false;
    }

    else if (z.length < 7 || !/[a-z]/.test(z) || !/[A-Z]/.test(z) || !/[0-9]/.test(z)) {
        alert("Password must be a minimum of 8 characters, with at least 1 number, 1 lower case and 1 upper case letter.");
        return false;
    }

    else if (z !== b) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
        return false;
    }


}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Many thanks,

Hopeless coder

Comment: Are you getting to the part of the code that executes the query? Is `$errors` empty? What are the values of the variables that you're using in the query? Do some basic debugging and find out exactly where the breakdown is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax errors in your connection script:

```
$dbcon = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL:' .mysqli_connect_error());
language encoding
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this is not valid PHP. Since you're just getting a blank page, you've probably got display_errors and error_reporting turned off. They should NEVER be off while developing/debugging. It's almost as bad as using the `@` suppression operator - the equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: Thanks for your honest answer Marc B I have removed all the suppression operators and changed my connection script to the w3schools mysqli version and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just an update - I found out how to switch the display errors on and was able then to find the root cause of the error. Problem now sorted